# Sending email with smtplib library with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sending email with smtplib library with the below Python program, however, I get a SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed error.

```
import smtplib

subject = 'This is a test subject'
body = 'This is a test body'
message = ("From: XXXX@gmail.com\r\nTo: YYYY@gmail.com\r\n\r\n{subject}\n\n{body}")

server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=465)

try:
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('XXXX@gmail.com', 'XXXX')
    server.sendmail('XXXX@gmail.com', 'YYYY.smithson@gmail.com', message)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    server.quit()
```

Full error code below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XXXX/PycharmProjects/New/Project/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=465)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 253, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 398, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

When trying out port 587 for Google SMTP servers I get an authentication error, so I imagine 465 is the correct TLS port. I have also seen another post about adding the 'From' and 'To' headers and therefore added in my own adaptation. I have also enabled POP3 and IMAP in both Gmail accounts.

Appreciate your help in advance, recently started Python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a different way to send emails with Python in SMTPLIB.

```
import smtplib
content = "-" # Enter your content here
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
main.login('EMAIL@something.com', 'PASSWORD TO YOUR ACCOUNT')
header = 'To:' + 'TO EMAIL' + '\n' + 'From:' \
         + 'FROM EMAIL' + '\n' + 'Subject: Sent email from python \n'
content = header + content
mail.sendmail('FROM EMAIL', 'TO EMAIL', content) # (1) = Sender, (2) = Receiver
mail.close
```

Be careful to not fake you sent the email from an account you don't own, if you do, it might cause some unwanted effects. Make sure that the emails you are typing in is valid and your own. Also, you might want to create a send email google account to send your mail to other people, because you will need to loosen security on that new email. First, create that gmail account and go to your circle avatar. Go to manage account > security > and toggle less secure apps to on. Don't use this email for everything, only use it to send emails through python, because it's safer.

Comment: Hi there, I tried the above but still get the same error unfortunately, replacing the relevant information where needed. This is on a test gmail account which I enabled POP3 / IMAP for, toggled that 'less secure apps' option off, tried on both ports 587 and 465, and have of course triple checked the username/password being entered.

Comment: And to add as well, 2FA is disabled on this account which I've read may cause an issue too...

Comment: Try reinstalling your smtplib or update it. Are you using Pycharm?

Comment: I am using Pycharm, version 2021.1.2, build no 211.7442.45. No IDE or plugin updates available when I checked now.

Comment: On the project that you are working in, on Pycharm, go to the top left and click file > settings. Then click project: NAME. Go to project interpreter and on the list in the box, find the smtplib and see if it needs any updates.

Comment: I thought smtplib is part of a preinstalled package? It's not in my interpreter list and not showing any erorrs in Python when importing the module?

Comment: Try this in your command prompt: pip install smtplib

Comment: I've just worked it out, it was the 'less secure apps access' option that you mentioned earlier, I must have thought I switched it on when I hadn't!!! Apologies for wasting your time on the further responses but now got it working :) Thank you so much, now to add this to my other project!